# put the canvas in center of screen

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my code to display a canvas on a background image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/GIF" href="res/favicon.ico"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="full-screen" content="yes"/>
    <meta name="screen-orientation" content="portrait"/>
    <meta name="x5-fullscreen" content="true"/>
    <meta name="360-fullscreen" content="true"/>



    <style>
        body, canvas, div {

            -moz-user-select: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    </style>

    <style type="text/css">

    body {

    background-image: url('bg.jpg');


    }

    </style>
</head>
<!--body style="padding:0; margin: 0; background: #000;"-->
<!--background-color: #cccccc;-->
<canvas id="gameCanvas" width="960" height="640"></canvas>
         <script src="frameworks/cocos2d-html5/CCBoot.js"></script>
         <script src="src/lib/build/build.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
         <script type="text/javascript">require('boot');</script> 
<script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But before it display the canvas in the center of web page, It will display as below:

[image]

Rather than in the center of the web page.

Your comment welcome.

Comment: aaand what did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this in modern browser([2dTransformCompatibility](http://caniuse.com/transforms2d) [3dTransformCompatibility](http://caniuse.com/transforms3d)) with css:

```
canvas {
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body, canvas, div {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

}
canvas {
     margin: auto auto auto auto
}
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 1):

For centering your webpage, you can calculate the difference between size of body and size of canvas.
For eg

diffHeight = (bodyHeight-canavasheight)  // difference in height
diffWidth = (bodyWidth-canvasWidth)  // difference in width

then you can put your margin-left equals to half of diffWidth and margin-top equals to half of diffHeight.

setting margin equals to auto is an good option but it sometimes doesn't center vertically.

Comment: I think its an great idea.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
canvas { 
    display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -moz-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
          align-items: center;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -moz-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
          justify-content: center;
    }
```